# Limit of sequence which leads to infinity divided by zero (because of my lack of skill)

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{4x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}-x\right)$$

I need help in finding this limit.

Comment: this hint is wrong!

Comment: You, right. For some reason I thought $x$ goes to zero. Sorry.

Comment: the searched limit is $-\frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it in the form
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \biggl(
  \frac{3x^2\bigl(\sqrt{4x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\,\bigr)}{3x^2}-x
\biggr)
$$
and simplify $3x^2$. Now change $x=1/t$ so you get
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}
\frac{\sqrt{4+t+t^2}-\sqrt{1+t+t^2}-1}{t}
$$
which is the derivative at $0$ of the function
$$
f(t)=\sqrt{4+t+t^2}-\sqrt{1+t+t^2}
$$
because $f(0)=1$, so
$$
f'(t)=\frac{2t+1}{2\sqrt{4+t+t^2}}-\frac{2t+1}{2\sqrt{1+t+t^2}}
$$
and you just need to compute $f'(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try putting it under the same denominator, then multiply by the denominators conjugate and see if nice stuff happens.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the first term by $$\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{\sqrt{4x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$$gives$$\begin{align}&\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{4x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}-x\right)\\\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x\right)\\\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\sqrt{4+\frac 1x+\frac{1}{x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac 1x+\frac{1}{x^2}}-1\right)\\\\&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{4+t+t^2}-\sqrt{1+t+t^2}-1}{t}\qquad (\text{set $t=\frac 1x$})\\\\&=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1+2t}{2\sqrt{4+t+t^2}}-\frac{1+2t}{2\sqrt{1+t+t^2}}\right)\quad(\text{apply L'Hôpital's rule})\\\\&=\color{red}{-\frac 14}\end{align}$$

Comment: It is possible to solve it wihtou L'Hopital rule? I do not know it officially on my course yet.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk: See egreg's answer.